# como lleno una lista desplegable en jsp con una consulta de mysql servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Necesito crear una lista desplegable en jsp con una consulta realizada en mysql estoy trabajando con mvc adjunto el servlet donde tengo los datos de la consulta pero no he podido mandar los datos a las lista desplegable y tambien adjunto la pagina jsp.

¿Me pueden decir como se puede hacer esto?

```
SeleccionarFechasDao dao = new SeleccionarFechasDao();
dao.CargarDatos();
ResultSet res = dao.CargarDatos();

List<GenerarFechas> fechas = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    while (res.next()) {

        /* codigo para agregar fechas */
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SeleccionarFechas.class.getName())
        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
request.getSession().setAttribute("GenerarFechas", fechas);
request.getRequestDispatcher("consulta.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Y aca es donde debe de ir la consulta de mysql en la lista desplegable

```
<label for="Fecha">Fecha</label>
<select type="text" name="Fecha" class="form-control" size="9"
    placeholder="Mes.Año" required="true">
    <!-- options -->
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de tu codigo JSP:

```
<%
    List<GenerarFechas> fechas = request.getSession().get("fechas");
%>
```

Pones aquí un foreach o un for que recorra 'fechas'

```
<% for(GenerarFechas fecha : fechas) { %>
    <option value="<%=fecha.getElMetodoQueTeTraeElID();">
        <%=fecha.getElMetodoQueTeTraeLaFecha(); %>
    </option>
<% } //Cerrar FOR %>
```

Espero haberte dado una idea.